# Python TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> when calculating standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, standard-deviation

I want to calculate the standard deviation from scratch. It's giving me a `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>` error.

I tried to cast `diff_squared` to list using `.tolist()` but it raised `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'` instead.

```
import pandas as pd

from math import sqrt

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Admission_Predict.csv')

# Mean
sums = 0
for m in range(len(df)):
    sums += df.iloc[m]
mean = sums / len(df)

# Square of difference of mean and each value
diff_squared = 0
for n in range(len(df)):
    diff_squared += (df.iloc[n].tolist() - mean) ** 2

# Standard deviation
stdv = sqrt(diff_squared / ((len(df)) - 1))
```

Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\Fibonacci recursive.py", line 18, in <module>
    stdv = sqrt(diff_squared / ((len(df)) - 1))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 141, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: *df.iloc[n].tolist() - mean* makes no sense. This is X - Y where X is a list and Y is a float

Comment: I recommend using built-in functions instead of inventing the wheel! first of all, convert all possible values in the column to numerical values then get rid of `NaN` values, and finally determine the STDV. Post a data sample for more explanation @meloqq

Comment: As @DarkKnight mentioned, `df.iloc[n].tolist() - mean` makes no sense. However changing it to `df.iloc[n]` works fine.